# Make a JavaScript Auto generator for visitors to my website

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a website that stores quotes and users can add some quotes to their favorite list. I want to be able to let those users generate a JavaScript snippet to put in their blog or website and this JavaScript will display their favorite quotes one by one every set period of time say 60 seconds.

I have been using Ruby on Rails which have a lot of the JavaScript out of the box so I didn't learn any JavaScript library or such.

I was wondering if you know what's the easiest way to do this whether by using JavaScript library, using Rails plugin or by using some external plugin.

Thanks,

Tam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you probably anticipate your users to show their quotes on blogs, forums, web sites etc., you cannot count on the availability of JavaScript. I suggest adopting an iframe approach: have a page in your site expose content based on a query string, that can be shown in an iframe. Provide the code to the user to paste into his site's html.

You want a sample? Look no further than [StackOverflow flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair) :).

Comment: that's something I will consider..Do you know a good resources to start?

Comment: What kind of resources can I help you with? Go to your profile page and click the "got flair?" link under your avatar. There's quite a good explanation (and source you can copy) there?

Comment: oooops. I got confused with the JS they had. I guess they provide both options

Answer (score 1):

You may consider just making the user's favorite quotes available as an RSS or atom feed. Then just find and use one of the many RSS reader widgets available.

Comment: I already have that...I just wanted to use js so it can more flexible with transitioning and customization

Comment: What I meant was, use one of the many JS based RSS reader widgets.